# lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(33, 34): An argument for 'value' was not provided

Tags: typescript, promise, nuxt.js

```
                                  22:16:16:25
```

TS2556: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0 or more.

```
           config.promise.then((...args: any[]) => {
                if (this._isCancelled) return;
                this._isCompleted = true;
                resolve(...args);
                        ^^^^^^^
            }, (error)=>{
                if (this._isCancelled) return;
                this._isCompleted = false;
                reject(error);
            });
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "ESNext.AsyncIterable",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxtjs/axios",
      "@nuxt/types",
      "types-lib/*"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

code is running better but getting error in the file

> After changing from **resolve(...args)** to **resolve(args)**

I am getting this error:

***Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T | PromiseLike'.
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'any[]'***

Also changed target to es6, es5, es2016, es2015 so on not worked

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by using:

```
`resolve(null);`
```

instead of:

```
'resolve();`
```

Comment: my code is `resolve(...args);` not 'resolve();`

Comment: just as @Terry responded,
use:   `resolve(args);` 
instead of: `resolve(...args);`

Answer (score 0):

`resolve()` only accepts a single argument. By doing `resolve(...args)` you are spreading an array of arbitrary length into arbitrary amount of positional arguments, which is not compatible with the interface.

Just pass the `args` directly so all arguments will be passed in an array, i.e. `resolve(args)`.

Comment: Even after changing, I am getting an error

Answer (score 0):

**Hey sorry for the late**

> I solved this issue

Changed This:

```
config.promise.then((...args: any[]) => {
                if (this._isCancelled) return;
                this._isCompleted = true;
                resolve(...args);
                        ^^^^^^^
            }, (error)=>{
                if (this._isCancelled) return;
                this._isCompleted = false;
                reject(error);
            });
```

To This:

```
config.promise.then((args: any) => {
                if (this._isCancelled) return;
                this._isCompleted = true;
                resolve(args);
                        
            }, (error)=>{
                if (this._isCancelled) return;
                this._isCompleted = false;
                reject(error);
            });
```