# Weird Error After Upgrading from Angular 10 to Angular 11

Tags: angular

After upgrading from Angular 10 to 11, I got the following error when I'm doing an ng serve:

```
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts:33:34
new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): Promise<T>;
An argument for 'value' was not provided.
```

This code is not even written by me. Why does this happen?

Rgds,
Benedict

Comment: This is an excerpt from my package.json:

Comment: Are you using promises in your code? It looks like you are using the empty resolve method. Just replace it with resolve(null).

Comment: This might help: [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763534/lib-es2015-promise-d-ts33-34-an-argument-for-value-was-not-provided)